# Particle System: XNA Framework HiDef profile does not support alpha blending on Vector4 textures

Tags: xna-4.0, particle-system

I found this great tutorial on making a particle system in XNA:
http://www.catalinzima.com/tutorials/4-uses-of-vtf/particle-systems/

The problem is that its written for an older version of xna and xna 4.0.

In the DoPhysicsPass method I get this exception:

XNA Framework HiDef profile does not support alpha blending or ColorWriteChannels when using rendertarget format Vector4.

Here is the method that is blowing up

```
    private void doPhysicsPass(string technique, RenderTarget2D resultTarget)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(temporaryRT);
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.White);
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        physicsEffect.CurrentTechnique = physicsEffect.Techniques[technique];
        if (isPhysicsReset)
        {
            physicsEffect.Parameters["positionMap"].SetValue(positionRT);
            physicsEffect.Parameters["velocityMap"].SetValue(velocityRT);
        }

        physicsEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();
        spriteBatch.Draw(randomTexture, new Rectangle(0, 0, particleCount, particleCount), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End(); //<-----     Exception thrown here

        GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(resultTarget);
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        physicsEffect.CurrentTechnique = physicsEffect.Techniques["CopyTexture"];
        physicsEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();
        spriteBatch.Draw(temporaryRT, new Rectangle(0, 0, particleCount, particleCount), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();
    }
```

Here is the initialization of randomTexture:

```
velocityRT = new RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, particleCount, particleCount, false, 
                                SurfaceFormat.Vector4, DepthFormat.None);
```

Can anyone offer some suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, are you sure you're setting the effect on the `SpriteBatch` correctly? I'm not sure you are. It looks like you've converted the tutorial, which is using the old pre-4.0 way of applying custom render settings ([details](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/19761/xna-3-0-disable-texture-filtering/19767#19767)).

I suspect you either need to be passing `SpriteSortMode.Immediate` to `Begin` (note that this will disable batching), **or** passing in your effect (probably *after* setting `CurrentTechnique`).

The second issue is simply explained by the exception. **You need to disable alpha blending** and `ColorWriteChannels`. I suspect that `ColorWriteChannels` is actually disabled anyway (the default). To disable alpha blending, try passing `BlendState.Opaque` to `SpriteBatch.Begin` (`AlphaBlend` is the default).

I've not tried updating the tutorial to XNA 4.0 myself - but I'm pretty sure that fixing either one or both of these things will fix your problem.